# Hyperledger Angular App - error message: "Could not find API route"

Tags: angularjs, hyperledger-composer

Using Hyperledger Fabric Composer I created a simple application.

However, when I try to interact with the application (which is served at http://localhost:4200), I keep getting the following error message:

```
Error: 404 - Could not find API route. Please check your available APIs.
```

This error message appears whatever I want to do (create new Participant/Asset, submit a transaction, ...)

I checked whether the error message had something to do with the application I created. So I also deployed another application I downloaded from the Internet. Again, the same error message appeared when I tried to interact with the UI.

```
       **********************************************************
```

Here's the long story:

After I had finished writing the code, I took the usual steps to obtain an Angular Web App:

Inside the folder of the app ("my_app"), I created a folder called "dist".
Inside folder "dist" I ran the following commands:

```
composer archive create -t dir -n ../

composer network install --archiveFile my_app@0.0.1.bna --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1

composer network start --networkName my_app --networkVersion 0.0.1 --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw

composer card import -f admin@my_app.card

//start rest-server:
composer-rest-server 

yo hyperledger-composer
```

After the last command I chose (from the menu) the option to create an "angular" application based on the business network "my_app".

A folder containing the angular-application was created (name of the folder: "angular").

Inside folder "angular", I ran the following command:

```
ng serve
```

Some output on the command line was created, among others, the following line:

```
** NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:4200 **
```

When I went to address http://localhost:4200 everything looked fine at first.

However, whenever I click on any of the buttons in the UI (e.g. on "Add Participant"), I get the following error message:

```
Error: 404 - Could not find API route. Please check your available APIs.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:

using

```
"npm start"
```

instead of

```
"ng serve"
```

avoids the problem.

FYI. There is a [tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial) that shows use of the Composer Angular generator incl the `npm start`sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and got the same error messgae. So i recreated the angular application using the yo hyperledger-composer tool but this time instead of choosing "Connect to existing REST API" I chose "Create new REST API" and then it connected fine on localhost:4200 while the rest server still ran on port 3000.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem with version 0.20 of the Composer CLI tools.  I solved the issue by editing the following in the /package.json file:

The "start" entry originally had "0.0.0.0" for the host value -

```js
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "build": "ng build",
    "prepack": "npm run build",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.js --host 0.0.0.0",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test --watch false",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  }
```

I changed that to "localhost" -

```js
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "build": "ng build",
    "prepack": "npm run build",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.js --host localhost",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test --watch false",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  }
```

Everything worked after restarting the Angular app with the new settings.

Answer (score -1):

I also encountered this error, I resolved it by running the composer and the angular app as a background process.

I installed the [forever package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) to run the two as a background process.

Then just killed the process if you're not gonna use it.